# (Clang Error) compilation error: ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o. Any ideas?

Tags: c++, macos, x86, clang

The full terminal output is as follows:

```
>g++ -std=c++98 -static mainP1.o  -o mainP1
>
>ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
>
>clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
>make: *** [mainP1] Error 1
```

I'm on a 2020 MacBook Pro with an intel CPU using Visual Studio Code. When I write basic OOP programs in C++ it compiles fine without any clang errors.  However, when working with big OOP programs with multiple classes inheriting from a base class I would get this error.

I tried searching online for solutions, but no solution or explanation was found. I double-checked my makefile to ensure I was not linking classes incorrectly.
I thought maybe I should just dual-boot with UBUNTU Linux to avoid this weird XCODE issue I was encountering with clang, but that was also a fruitless endeavor.

Comment: Does it link if you change `-std=c++98` to `-std=c++11` ? And do you really need C++98 (from 1998) ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I, unfortunately, have to use c++98 for my university

Comment: But does it compile with `-std=c++11` as knowing this might point to the problem?

Comment: @RichardCritten also no. I tried seeing if it wasn't my makefile, but that also does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter what program you compile. If the crt file is missing no compilation for C++ or C will work. This file is part of the C runtime required for every program. You must have not installed the compiler correctly for your platform.

Comment: This line is throwing me _"...When I write basic OOP programs in C++ it compiles fine without any clang errors...."_ how does this work if the above command line does not ?  What is different between the 2 test cases ?

Comment: @RichardCritten when multiple classes inherit from one class. Abstraction of classes, ect.

Comment: Are you building both the working and non-working exactly the same? With the exact same command, the exact same options and flags? Because what you describe is really irrelevant to the building and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my compiler path in Visual Studio Code.
I changed it to clang++, and now all my code compiles and executes without any problems.

How I changed it:

1. CMD + SHIFT + P
2. Typed in: C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)
3. Made sure that "Mac" was selected under configuration name.
4. Changed Compiler Path to: /usr/bin/clang++